# Getting number of $index of a table row in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-table, row

How can I get the number of index from the following example in **js (angularjs)**

```
        <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="customer in group.data>
            <td>({{$index + 1}}) </td> // << get this number ???
            <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.city}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.tel}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.etc}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.reg}}</td>
        </tr>
```

The index in my case is **10**. But how can I get this value as variable to work with in other functions?

I tried it with `$index.length` etc. But I didn't get the value 10.

Comment: could you post the code where you want to use $index?

Comment: Could you create a simple fiddle/plunker with what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correct understand question - you get count of items in array with:

```
group.data.length
```

Comment: aaaaaah soo easy and I thaught to complicated all the time. Yes you have understand me correct. Thank you very much! I have my count of the items from each table group now :)